# How to get union types of object values inside array?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have an array

```
const list = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'b'}, {id: 'c'}] as const;
```

and I want to get union type from all values of field `id`, i.e. `'a'|'b'|'c'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typeof list[number]["id"]` to get a union of all the `id` values.

```js
const list = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'b'}, {id: 'c'}] as const;
type Values = typeof list[number]["id"];
```

Comment: I tried in playground, and it did not work, any specific TS settings you are using?

Comment: No, here's the playground link that's working for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gbwQEwFwwDkAhoQL4A0M2+RARuVTQYcOQLozEQyiRQBuALAAoUVACeABwCmMAGrE4AVxk80k2SABm8JFHRhlAWzoyATu3QAiXNfYCgA

Comment: ah, I have a typo -- an extra comma in the array. so it works. thank you!

Comment: Great! No problem.